# PyQt - "tell" QFileDialog to ignore alias?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm using OSX and i'm trying to load an image sequence using QFileDialog.
My image sequence is:

```
image.000001.tif
image.000002.tif
image.000003.tif
...
```

However, all of the images in that sequences are aliases of another image, let's call it `original.tif`

So when i try to load the file name into a string variable using QFileDialog, it returns the file name of the original image rather than the alias.

How can i fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those names are *symbolic links* to `original.tif` you may want to disable symlink resolution:

```
dialog.setOptions(QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks);
```

The documentation for the [`options` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#options-prop) states that by default all options are disabled, which means that by default `QFileDialog` *does* resolve symlinks.
Resolving a symlink (symbolic link) means obtaining the name of the real file that is being pointed to.

---

Note that if you are using the static methods such as [`getOpenFileName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName) you can still pass the options for the dialog as the last parameter, for example:

```
QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent, "Open file", "/home/user", "", None,
                            QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks);
```

Also note that the documentation for this method says:

> **On Unix/X11, the normal behavior of the file dialog is to resolve and
>   follow symlinks.** For example, if `/usr/tmp` is a symlink to `/var/tmp`,
>   the file dialog will change to `/var/tmp` after entering `/usr/tmp`. If
>   options includes `DontResolveSymlinks`, the file dialog will treat
>   symlinks as regular directories.

Comment: Okay great thanks! When i get the filename and put it into a QListWidget i don't get that sliding arrow at the bottom that you can drag and see the full file path name (if it's long). It happens only when i use that DontResolveSymlinks option, not sure why. Could it be a bug in QT?

Comment: @Gambit2007 I don't know. It might be. But that should be the topic for an other question.